# Arrays in Methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm working on an assignment with the directions as follows,

Write a method that when passed an integer search value, and an array of integers will      return true if the search value is in the array, otherwise returns false. Call the method and  print the result in main.

Here is what I have so far,

```
public class ArrayLab {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {15, -2, 18, -9, 90, 17, 981};
    int index;   
 boolean isThere = searchValue(15, array);
    System.out.println(isThere);

public static boolean searchValue(int search, int[] array) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean isThere = true;
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
          if (search == array[index])
           isThere = true; 
          else
            isThere = false; } // end for

 return isThere;
   } // end searchValue 

} // end class
```

The issues I"m having have varied depending on the several ways I've treid to rewrite this. As it is now, I'm not receiving any errors, but the value being returned is always false no matter what number I pass to the method from main.

Any suggestions as to how I can correct this issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a perfect time to try using a debugger in your IDE. Walking through the code line by line as the compiler executes it is a brilliant way to learn to be a better programmer.

Comment: It's also a perfect time to use an editor the fixes code formatting .. (I simply don't bother to read code that is not consistently formatted. Programming is like art - and I'm not into paint splatters.)

Comment: What's the use of your `Scanner` in the `searchValue` method ?

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone! @ZouZou, initially I had planned to include a print statement to ask the user for what value they would like to search the array for, but ended up just passing it a value instead. Thanks for pointing out that I should delete that since it doesn't need to be there anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break after the number has been found. Otherwise, you keep checking the other numbers as well. Thus, if the last number would return false, you'd just see "false"

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (search == array[index]) { 
        isThere = true;
        break; 
    } else
        isThere = false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop as follows, you need o break the loop whenever you encounters the element,other wise the loop will continue till last element

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
          if (search == array[index])
           isThere = true;
           break; 
          else
            isThere = false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `break` once you find that value matches.

Answer (score 0):

1)Your given code won't compile  since you wrote another method inside main method. That's an compiler error

2)You need to `return` from  when you found the result. Now It's proceeding further and checking again.

With simplification, It's like

```
public static boolean searchValue(int search, int[] array) {
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
          if (search == array[index])
              return true;
     }      
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return true when you find the number. Of course, you should return false if you can't. So I think you want something like this

```
public static boolean searchValue(int search, int[] array) {
  if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
    for (int i : array) {
      if (i == search) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that if condition is successful then we should break the loop and return. That is missing